# Query posts by custom taxonomy ID

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called `portfolio` and a custom taxonomy called `build-type` (acting as categories)

I am trying to query `portfolio` posts by `build-type` ID e.g. all Portfolio posts in "Hotels" (id=4 for that taxonomy)

```
// gets the ID from a custom field to show posts on a specific page   
$buildType = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'build_type_id', true);
// run query
query_posts(array( 
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'showposts' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'build-type',
        'terms' => $buildType,
        'field' => 'term_id'
    ),
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

Currently it's calling **all** `portfolio` posts and not just those with the `build-type` ID

For `'field' => 'term_id'` should I be using `term_id`, `tag_ID`, `id` or something else?

Anyone know how to get this working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved it with help from: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30476/query-posts-by-custom-taxonomy-id

`tax-query` needs to be an array of arrays

The final solution is:

```
// gets the ID from a custom field to show posts on a specific page
$buildType = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'build_type_id', true);
// run query
query_posts(array( 
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'showposts' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'build-type',
            'terms' => $buildType,
            'field' => 'term_id',
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC' )
);
```

On github here:

https://gist.github.com/1275191

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a WP-gury and I have invested hours and hours trying to solve the same problem. Eventually I found this blog post: http://richardsweeney.com/blog/wordpress-3-0-custom-queries-post-types-and-taxonomies/

The answer is somewhat semi-bad: apparently you can't filter like this for custom post types (it is only possible for posts), which is a shame!

What I did work was this:

$args['custom_tax'] = 'custom_tax_slug'; 
query_posts($args);

Hope it helps!

//Mike